# How to create routes that loads up a new page

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Newbie to this entire web development domain.

I have a main page and a registration page. Whenever I navigate to subscription page I find the contents of registration page appended at the bottom the main page. How can I create routes in a way where both pages are separate. So when I click home I only see my main page and when I click registration I only see the registration page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: General advice: please reduce the code to the simplest possible version which demonstrates the problem and then post it. In this case, I'd like to see something like: a router that has 2 routes, and a simple html file with two templates and a body. I suspect you are just not using `{{yield}}` properly, but I need to see the code first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use routing on the server side to serve a separate html page. It can be useful for landing pages, etc.

Usually it's done in Meteor by passing a middleware to `connect` npm module which is accessible in `WebApp.connectHandlers` or you could use [Iron-Router's](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#server-side-routing) server-side routing feature.